# ng-click not triggering Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I need to call function in type script from the view using angular.js. Technologies that i use are angular.js typescript and ASP.Net MVC3.

this is the link in UI.

```
<div id="left_aside" ng-controller="MyGivingPortfolioController">
 <div class="charity_portfolio_tile" ng-repeat="Tile in VM.Tiles.TileContainerEntity" >
    <a href="#" ng-click="Delete(Tile.Id)" class="delete_button">delete</a>
 </div>
```

when i click this link it doesnt invoke the method.

```
 Delete = function (Id:number) {
    alert("Called " + Id.toString());
}
```

then i changed this function like below.

```
Delete(charityID: number) {
    var id = charityID;
    alert(id.toString());
}
```

though i changed the code, it didn't work. Actually i don't know the reason for this.

```
class MyController implements IMyController {


Tiles: TileContainerEntities;

constructor($scope, $http: ng.IHttpService) {
    $scope.VM = this;
    $http.get("/API/PrivateAPI/Test/1").success((responce) =>{this.BusinessReponseList = responce;  });
}



Delete = function (Id:number) {
    alert("Called " + Id);
}

//Delete(charityID: number) {
//    var id = charityID;
//    alert(id.toString());
//}
```

}

Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: could you share your controller code !!

Comment: it should be `VM.Delete`. see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the href's ng-click to be `ng-click="VM.Delete(Tile.Id)"`

i.e.:

```
<div class="charity_portfolio_tile" ng-repeat="Tile in VM.Tiles.TileContainerEntity" >
      <a href="#" ng-click="VM.Delete(Tile.Id)" class="delete_button">delete</a>
</div>
```

*Just useful info not directly related to answer:* Be aware of scope inheritance : http://youtu.be/WdtVn_8K17E?t=5m34s . An ng-repeat creates a new scope :)